# List of theorem dots overlapping with theorem name

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, thmtools

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,thmtools,tikz,xparse,lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\th@plain{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \itshape % body font
}
\def\th@definition{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \normalfont % body font
}
\newlength{\mw@mystyleposthead}
\setlength{\mw@mystyleposthead}{.5em}
\newcommand{\growposthead}[1]{\advance\mw@mystyleposthead by #1}
\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep, headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{}, bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape, postheadspace=\mw@mystyleposthead, name={\ignorespaces}, numbered=no, headpunct=.]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}mo}
    {\IfValueTF{#3}
            {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2,label=#3]}
            {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2]}
        }
    {\end{@thmattr}}
\newcommand\mw@mklistcmd{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{% CHECK: why p@edef?
    \@nx\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}%
  }%
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\thmt@thmname\ \csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname\punct@list}%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow% default:show
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\thmt@listnumwidth}{8em}
\renewcommand\l@@thmattr{\edef\mw@tempdima{\widthof{\thmt@shortoptarg}}\@dottedtocline{1}{2.5em}{\@nx\mw@tempdima}}
\newcommand{\punct@list}{.}
\renewcommand{\ll@@thmattr}{\protect\numberline{\thmt@shortoptarg}}
\let\thmt@mklistcmd\mw@mklistcmd
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{teorspec}{della palla pelosa}[pallapelosa]
Non esiste un campo conitnuo tangente ad una sfera $S^2$ che non si annulli in nessun punto.
\end{teorspec}
\begin{teorspec}{del differenziale totale}[thm:difftot]
Bla bla bla differenziale eccetera.
\end{teorspec}
\listoftheorems
\end{document}
%13 minimalizing and 1 comment. 10 making compile and 2 comment. 4 minimalizing and 2 comment.
```

Here is its output:

[image]

[image]

Since this is supposed to be minimal, I didn't change the language of the title of the list, nor did I include non-`teorspec` theorems which really motivate the value 8 for `\thmt@listnumwidth`. Anyway the problem is evident: the dots of the list are going over the name of the two `teorspec` theorems. Seeing this, I tried having a look at the code behind the list. I found out `\csname l@<first argument of \contentsline>\endcsname` is executed inside `\contentsline`, which I found in the loe. So I redefined it as you can see, with no effect whatsoever. So how do I stop those dots from overlapping with theorem names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the titles where the numbers are meant to be.  You can just remove the `\numberline` in `\ll@thmattr`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,thmtools,tikz,xparse,lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\th@plain{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \itshape % body font
}
\def\th@definition{%
  \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
  \normalfont % body font
}
\newlength{\mw@mystyleposthead}
\setlength{\mw@mystyleposthead}{.5em}
\newcommand{\growposthead}[1]{\advance\mw@mystyleposthead by #1}
\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep, headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{}, bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape, postheadspace=\mw@mystyleposthead, name={\ignorespaces}, numbered=no, headpunct=.]{mystyle}
 \declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
 \NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}mo}
     {\IfValueTF{#3}
             {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2,label=#3]}
             {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2]}
         }
     {\end{@thmattr}}
\newcommand\mw@mklistcmd{%
  \@xa\protected@edef\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname{% CHECK: why p@edef?
    \@nx\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@nx\thmt@listnumwidth}%
  }%
  \ifthmt@isstarred
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\protect\let\protect\autodot\protect\@empty}%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \else
    \@xa\def\csname ll@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
      \protect\numberline{\thmt@thmname\ \csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname\punct@list}%
      \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg\else\protect\thmtformatoptarg{\thmt@shortoptarg}\fi
    }%
  \fi
  \@xa\gdef\csname thmt@contentsline@\thmt@envname\endcsname{%
    \thmt@contentslineShow% default:show
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\thmt@listnumwidth}{0em}
\renewcommand\l@@thmattr{\edef\mw@tempdima{\widthof{\thmt@shortoptarg}}\@dottedtocline{1}{2.5em}{\@nx\mw@tempdima}}
\newcommand{\punct@list}{.}
\renewcommand{\ll@@thmattr}{\thmt@shortoptarg}
\let\thmt@mklistcmd\mw@mklistcmd
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{teorspec}{della palla pelosa}[pallapelosa]
Non esiste un campo conitnuo tangente ad una sfera $S^2$ che non si annulli in nessun punto.
\end{teorspec}
\begin{teorspec}{del differenziale totale}[thm:difftot]
Bla bla bla differenziale eccetera.
\end{teorspec}
\listoftheorems
\end{document}
%13 minimalizing and 1 comment. 10 making compile and 2 comment. 4 minimalizing and 2 comment.
```

Comment: Now I see! The `\numberline` was the problem. Instead of `\l@@thmattr`, I should have worked on `\@tempdima` if I wanted to keep `\numberline`. Btw, your original proposal (adding empty argument to `\numberline`) gave me a huge space before the title. Accepting answer.

Comment: `\numberline` puts its contents flushleft in a box of width `\@tempdima`, so yes my first version had that space still present.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX warns you:

```
Overfull \hbox (43.50002pt too wide) detected at line 2
\T1/ntxtlf/m/n/10 Teorema del differenziale totale
```

and increasing the width by 44pt solves the over printing, change line 44 to

```
\renewcommand{\thmt@listnumwidth}{\dimexpr 8em + 44pt\relax}
```

[image]

Note that this width is designed for section numbers, the section title normally goes in the following argument if you compare with table of contents markup but I did not address that here.

Comment: Why does the redefinition of `\l@@thmattr` do that? After all, it alters what should be taken as arguments and puts something else instead of `\thmt@listnumwidth`…

Comment: @MickG I see Andrew has just answered that.

Comment: How did you achieve the red boxes?